# VS 2010 C++ Crash when deleting an array of structures

Tags: c++, structure, delete-operator

I have a class with a member function mBoundingBox made up of the following struct

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int xMin;
    unsigned int yMin;
    unsigned int xMax;
    unsigned int yMax;
} boundingBox;

class CImgProc
{
public:
    CImgProc(void);
    virtual ~CImgProc(void);
...
    boundingBox *mBoundingBox;
...
}
```

In code I allocate the member:

```
mBoundingBox = new boundingBox [mBlobCnt];
```

piddle around with it (don't assign any pointers to it, just using array indexing), then, when I exit I:

```
if (mBoundingBox != NULL) delete [] mBoundingBox;
```

and this is causing an error.

Any input?

Updated info. The error does occur at termination in the destructor. The message generated by VS is:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in ProcImage.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, ...

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while ProcImage.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

I am setting the pointer to NULL in the constructor and then allocating (with new) when I need to. The pointer is valid, but apparently not on the heap (break lands in dbgheap.c).

Once I allocate the memory, I don't happen to do any pointer magic with it. In this case I am looping through an image and gather stats. Then I use the stats stored in this memory to draw back into my image, but, again, in a rather brute force manner, so nothing else makes use of this memory.

It is legal for me to use new to create an array of structs isn't it?

Doh!!!  Sorry to waste ya'lls time.  I dug back in and discovered that my creation and destruction are fine, but somewhere in the middle I set the value of `mBoundingBox[X]`. whatever where it turns out X is the dim of the array created.
Typical user error, just a surprising place for the bug to show up.

Comment: It's going to take a lot more code to see what the problem is.

Comment: mBoundingBox* mboundingbox = new boundingBox [mBlobCnt]; it shouldnot be like this?

Comment: @AliKazmi no that is not correct, `mBoundingBox*` is not the pointer type `boundingBox*` is the type. `mBoundingBox` is just the name of the member variable.

Comment: What is crashing? VS 2010 C++ or your compiled program?

Comment: First guess: making copies without defining a copy constructor, leading to double deletes.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are deleting your array twice. To manage it better use

```
delete[] mBoundingBox;
mBoundingBox = 0;
```

instead of

```
if (mBoundingBox != NULL) delete [] mBoundingBox;
```

or even better use a smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

first of all the following check is wrong

```
if (mBoundingBox != NULL) delete [] mBoundingBox;
```

new does not returns NULL when it fails to allocate memory, rather it throws an exception.

use nothrow version of "new" if you want to proceed like you are doing. In nothrow version new will return NULL instead of throwing an exception.

```
mBoundingBox = new (std::nothrow) boundingBox [mBlobCnt];
```